# Flashing dialog box when I click outside of it

Tags: .net, vb.net

I would like that when a dialog box is opened, if I click outside of it, the dialog box will blink. How to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, what you are asking is how to do a modal dialog box. Without knowing the language you're using, I'll give you an example in C# and VB.NET...

```
// Consider the following with a form named AboutBox
var frm = new AboutBox();
frm.ShowDialog(); // Clicking on the calling form will cause this to be highlighted
```

The same in Visual Basic is as follows...

```
' AboutBox being the form
Dim frm As New AboutBox()
frm.ShowDialog()
```

Doing the same in WPF has a method of the same name so the code will look the same.

Comment: Hello, Fabulous. Sorry, I did not specify the programming language: VB.net.
Accuracy: when this modal dialog box is open, if I click outside this box, it should flash. What code to add for this event to occur.

Comment: @Eratos You do not add code for this event to occur. This event occurs because it's a standard behaviour to flash the active modal dialog title if you click on the parent window. If you do not see it happening, it must be because you are using Windows 10 where by default the window title is white, so it flashes between white and white which cannot be seen. Set the title bar color in the settings to see the flashing.

Comment: GSerg. I created a form without title, it represents a graphic background and a text of information. I would like the whole shape to flash. Is not the "FlashWindowEx" function reserved for this event?

Comment: Do you meant there's no title bar on the form that you want to flash? The flashing you initially described is what Windows does automatically if a user clicks outside the dialog box but within the application itself. It flashes the border and title bar. `ShowDialog` ensures the dialog form is always displayed above the calling form and cannot lost focus to it's owner without being explicitly dismissed.

Comment: Fabuleux. Exactly, there is no title bar in the form. I want only the border of the shape to blink. I tested my application: the border does not blink. :(

Comment: To succeed, I think I should use the FlashWindowsEx function.

Comment: I've written the code necessary to use `FlashWinodowEx` manually but without a control box, title bar and all I cannot see any visual indication of the flashing happening.(I'm on Winfows 10, if you are on another version I'm not sure how that will behave). Also, when I made it non modal and clicked away from the form, it didn't seem to flash. Also making it modal without a border didn't have any visual feedback when I clicked away from it. You may need to use a title bar and the code above, or implement a custom way to flash the Form yourself.